# When using nested AsycTask in activity will handler reference remain after onDestroy

Tags: android, android-memory

I have sample code which very simply does some heavy work and sends a message to a handler to update the UIThread. My concern is with the handler reference i am passing to the constructor.  If my activity gets destroyed while the asncTask is still running will the handler reference not be null ?

```
    public class SomeActivity extends Activity
{
    private static final int UPDATE_BUTTON_TEXT = 1;
    private static final SomeActivity me = null;

    private static Handler handler = new Handler() { 
        public void handleMessage(Message msg)  {
          if (me == null) return;

          switch (msg.what)  {
            case UPDATE_BUTTON_TEXT:
              Button btn = (Button) me.findViewById(R.id.someButton);
              btn.setText((String) msg.obj);
          }
        }
    };

    private View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View view) {
            new SomeLongRunningTask().execute();
        }
    };

    private static class SomeLongRunningTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        private Handler handler;

        public SomeLongRunningTask(Handler handler)  {
            this.handler = handler;
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(30000); // replace with some background logic
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

            return true;
        }



          @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
//can the handler be null here if activity is destroyed ????
                Message msg = handler.obtainMessage(UPDATE_BUTTON_TEXT);
                msg.obj = "success"
                handler.sendMessage(msg);
            }
        }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final Button someButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.someButton);
        someButton.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        me = this;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        me = null;

        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the reference of the handler is going to be retained in memory until it has a reference count > 0.

I think you should use [AsyncTask().onProgressUpdate](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate(Progress...)) for updating progress on UI, which does what you're trying to do.

**EDIT**

If you're updating ui in onPostExecute then you don't need to use onProgressUpdate(my apologies).

Just use an interface as a callback function like below:

```
private interface Callback {
    void updateUI(String value);
}

private static class SomeLongRunningTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Boolean> {
    private Callback mCallback;

    public SomeLongRunningTask(Callback callback)  {
        mCallback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        mCallback.updateUI("success");
    }
}

// somewhere else...
Callback callback = new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void updateUI(String value) {
        Button btn = (Button) me.findViewById(R.id.someButton);
        btn.setText((String) msg.obj);
    }
};

new SomeLongRunningTask(callback).execute();
```

Also it doesn't seem right to have a handler instance as a static variable. It will last until the class is unloaded.

Comment: Im using a static class. How can i reference the view this way?

Comment: Handler won't be destroyed until the AsyncTask holds it's reference. If you're really worried about leaking handler, you should consider stopping AsyncTask in onDestroy callback.

Comment: Now i would leak the callback right? Its same as handler.

Comment: No you won't unless you declare callback instance as a activity's class member.

Comment: The "static handler" instance is going to remain until the SomeActivity class is unloaded from memory and I don't see any reason to have the instance as a static variable.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule, whenever I write an `AsyncTask` subclass, I use a pattern like this:

```
    private WeakReference<Callback> mCallbackRef;

    public MyAsyncTask(Callback callback)  {
        mCallbackRef = new WeakReference<>(callback);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        if (mCallbackRef != null) {
            Callback callback = mCallbackRef.get();
            if (callback != null) {
                callback.updateUI("success");
            }
        }
    }
```